# Estimate $\hat{\beta}$ in linear regression for given data

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

> For data $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  2 \\  3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\  5 \\  3 \end{bmatrix}$, fit a linear model $y=ax+b+\varepsilon$ using the formula $\hat{\beta}=\left ( X^TX\right)^{-1}X^TY$.

This exercise should be really simple, but I have some doubts about my reasoning.

Let $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i+\varepsilon$ describe the i-th sample. The matrix of regressors is  $X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore $\left ( X^TX\right)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 14 & 6\\  6 & 3 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{7}{3} & 1\\ 1 & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $X^TY=\begin{bmatrix}12\\ 23\end{bmatrix}$.

The product of the matrix multiplication is:

$\hat{\beta}=\left ( X^TX\right)^{-1}X^TY = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{7}{3} & 1\\ 1 & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}12\\ 23\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}40\\ 18.5\end{bmatrix}$

Thus $\beta_0 = b = 40$ and $\beta_1 = a = 18.5$, meaning that the final linear model would be:

$y = 18.5x + 40 + \varepsilon$.

Hover, this seems unlikely, because graph of such line would be way above the given points. Am I making a mistake in my calculations? If so, where my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: Your matrix of regressors is transposed.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted from [math.SE]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543819/estimate-hat-beta-in-linear-regression-for-given-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix of regressors is $$X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1& 3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then
$$(X^TX)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 6 \\ 6 & 14 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{7}{3} & -1 \\ -1 & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Also
$$X^Ty=\begin{bmatrix} 12 \\ 23\end{bmatrix}.$$

Together,
$$(X^TX)^{-1}(X^Ty)=\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Your regression equation is $$y=5-\frac{1}{2}x+\varepsilon.$$

The predicted points you will find, with this regression line, are
$$\hat{y}=5-\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{9}{2} \\ 4 \\ \frac{7}{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 4.5 \\ 4 \\ 3.5 \end{bmatrix},$$

which all are close to the true values.

Comment: Please be cautious about answering homework questions. Our policies are detailed in the `[self-study]` tag's [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I thought the criteria was showing how much work they had already done and what approaches they had tried. I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: No, no, @AnnaSdTC, there is no need to apologize. My comment is just a heads up.